# Magento2: How to get product collection with pagination wise using ajax?

Tags: magento2, ajax, pagination

I want to get the product collection using ajax with pagination.

I have implement the product collection using ajax but pagination is not working.

Comment: Do you want to implement this part on category page?

Comment: No, I have created own module for product collection using ajax.

Comment: But how can implement pagination.

Comment: Please, show your code.

Comment: Can you share chat box